# NumIterations updating outside for loop

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why NumIterations is changing.  It's outside the loop.  It should remain 5 but sum should update exponentially by 2.

```
var NumIterations = 5; 

    document.write ("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>", NumIterations );


 var sum = 0.01;

 for (var i=0; i<=NumIterations; i++)

    { 
      document.write (sum + "<br/>");
        sum=sum*2;
    }
```

Comment: The `document.write` calls are probably causing your DOM to reload.  What happens if you replace them with `console.log`?  (Whenever possible, you should *avoid* using `document.write` as it can have unintended consequences depending on when/where it is loaded in your DOM)

Comment: please describe the behaviour of your code more accurately, including the output you're getting compared to the output you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

It's not changing. The way your code is written is that it's writing `"Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: "+5+"0.01"` and so it looks like it is saying: "Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: 50.01" but it's just because you need a break before the 0.01.

If you add a `<br/>` after the first part it will work as expected.

```js
var NumIterations = 5;

document.write("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>");
document.write(NumIterations);
document.write("<br/>");

var sum = 0.01;

for (var i = 0; i <= NumIterations; i++)

{
  document.write(sum + "<br/>");
  sum = sum * 2;
}
```

Comment: this is not correct, the second parameter of `document.write()` is a delay in ms

Answer (score 0):

You don't have logically error, just add "`<br>`" before you sum printing to separete your `NumIterations` and `sum` printing

```
var NumIterations = 5;
document.write ("<b>Sequence of numbers up to iteration number: </b>", NumIterations );
var sum = 0.01;
for (var i=0; i<=NumIterations; i++){ 
    document.write ("<br/>"+ sum );
    sum=sum*2;
}
```

[Working](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/w3842bmc/)